# Mysql keeps printing "->" after command

Tags: mysql

I'm playing with mysql on my localhost.
Everytime I write some commands to console it starts to print "->" all the time and doesnt react to any commands except "\c" which goes back to mysql>

It looks like that:

```
mysql> show binary logs
    ->
    ->
    ->
```

and keeps printing "->" whenever i press Enter

Any ideas?

Comment: then type semicolon `;`

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon is used to terminate statements in mysql.

```
SELECT id FROM users LIMIT 0,1; SELECT username FROM users LIMIT 0,2;
```

But there are some mysql command in which semicolon can be omitted.

```
Command provided by help like: clear, help, print, quit, use, etc
```